# Group_Concat in Concat not working with NULL values

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dept` (
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `dept` (`did`, `dname`) VALUES
(1, 'Hi'),
(2, NULL),
(3, 'Hello');
```

Then I have a query

```
select group_concat(concat(did,"','",dname) separator '),(') as Result from dept
```

It is producing result as `1','Hi'),('3','Hello`

**Question:** How can I get result from above query as `1','Hi'),('2','NULL'),('3','Hello`

It is missing the rows which have NULL values but I need to fetch all

[**Link for SQL Fiddle Demo of question**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/158d5/1)

**UPDATE:** If I have more than one or all columns allowing NULL, Is there some way to apply COALESCE once for all or have to apply individually at each Column?

Comment: I have another example of groupconcat in a concat
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql/13451984#13451984

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this, use `COALESCE`

```
.., COALESCE(dname, 'NULL'),..
```

making it `NULL` string visible. [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d82b/4)

Comment: Please guide if two or all columns can have NULL values then do I have to use `COALESCE` with each column or there is some method to do this once for all?

Comment: unfortunately none, you need to individually add `COALESCE` on each column.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySQL aggregate function documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

> Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values.

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to replace the nulls with a string, since they would be eliminated by the aggregate function.  For example `COALESCE(dbname, 'NULL')` will return the *string* `NULL` if `dbname IS NULL`.  Its purpose is to return the first *non-null* of the arguments you give it, and can therefore return a default value.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(did,"','", COALESCE(dname, 'NULL')) SEPARATOR "'),('") AS Result
FROM dept
```

Comment: Your solution is quite well explained and acceptable. Please Just replace separator `'),('` to `"'),('"` as I have done it in question and sqlfiddle demo

Comment: @Sami edited above. You can also escape single quotes as in `'\'),(\''`

Answer (score 0):

Hope following query will serve your purpose

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
IF(dname IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(did,"','",dname), CONCAT(did,"','NULL")) 
SEPARATOR '),(') AS Result FROM dept
```