# MySQL query to find similar but not duplicated row

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query to retrieve machinery stop codes and failure descriptions that looks like a duplicate search query but it is quite different.

Here's my source table

[image]

I'm using this query

```
SELECT `TestDups`.`MachineID`
     , `TestDups`.`Code`
     , `TestDups`.`StopTime`
  FROM `TestDups`
 WHERE `TestDups`.`Code` IN ( SELECT `TestDups`.`Code`
                                FROM `TestDups`
                               GROUP BY `TestDups`.`Code`
                              HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 )
 ORDER BY `TestDups`.`MachineID`
```

which returns this:

[image]

but I would like it to return this:

[image]

How can I reach my goal?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have a question please put _all_ relevant information in your question; not on an external site.

Comment: I _think_ you're looking for the sum of the stoptimes for the machineid, code combination with the greatest count? Can you please update your question to give a description of what you would like?

Comment: Yes Ben,if yuo look at CCM61 you will see 2 record with the code 130 with a SopTime of 10 and 30.

My query should retrive MachineID=CCM61 , Code=130 , StopTime=40 , Num=2.

For CCM66 (code 110) the query must retrive :
MachineID=CCM66 , Code=110 , StopTime=15 , Num=2.

In few words , for each MachineID I wan retreive, for each different Code, the StopTime Sum and the its occurence number.

Answer (score 2):

Something like following will work;

```
SELECT ... SUM(StopTime), COUNT(*) as Num FROM ... GROUP BY MACHINEID, CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this query would produce your desired result. I have given link for the demo as well

```
select MachineID,Code,sum(stoptime) as StopTime, count(*) as Num from 
TestDups group by MachineID,code order by machineid
```

[**Link for SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f81e/2)

Comment: @user1709570 Snapshots are good but providing your table structure and data makes it pretty much explained/clear e.g. you can have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653678/group-concat-concat-not-working-with-null-and-not-null-values