# MySQL Query to find most similar numerical row

Tags: mysql, similarity

In a MySQL database, I am attempting to find the most similar row across a number of numerical attributes. This problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662892/mysql-query-to-find-similar-but-not-duplicated-row) but includes a flexible number of comparisons and a join table.

### Database

The database consists of two tables. The first table, users, is what I'm trying to compare.

```
id | self_ranking
----------------------------------
1       | 9
2       | 3
3       | 2
```

The second table is a series of scores which the user gave to particular items.

```
id | user_id | item_id | score
----------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1       | 4
2  | 1       | 2       | 5
3  | 1       | 3       | 8
4  | 1       | 4       | 3
```

### Task

I want to find the "most similar" user to a given one, valuing all the ranked items equally (along with the self score). Thus, a perfect match would be the user who has ranked all the same items in exactly the same manner & has rated himself the same, while the next most optimal choice would be one whose ranking of one item differs slightly.

I'm running into difficulty with:

- Joining the two tables in an efficient manner
- Dealing with the fact that not all users are ranking the same items. We only want to compare rankings of identical items.

Could someone help me construct a reasonable query? I'm not terribly strong with MySQL, so sorry if this answer should be obvious.

### Output

If user 4 has ranked himself 8 and items 1=>4 and 2=>5, then I'd like to have the query for user 4's closest user to return 1, the user_id of the closest user.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how `users.self_ranking` is relevant to your question (if indeed it is at all)?

Comment: In that case, can you please edit your question with the expected output table?

Comment: @eggyal, it should be considered just another ranking (ie. users ranking themselves as an "item").

Comment: You can imagine what you need, so can you put that EXPECTED output result in the same format you put your current tables?

Comment: Why doesn't self_ranking count on the "perfect match"? What does "slightly" mean in than sentence?

Comment: Self_ranking does matter, equally with rankings of other items. I have clarified this in the question. Slightly would mean differed by one point (ex. ranked item 1 a 5 instead of a 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   u2.user_id

-- join our user to their scores
FROM     (users u1 JOIN scores s1 USING (user_id))

-- and then join other users and their scores
    JOIN (users u2 JOIN scores s2 USING (user_id))
      ON s1.item_id  = s2.item_id
     AND u1.user_id != u2.user_id

-- filter for our user of interest
WHERE    u1.user_id = ?

-- group other users' scores together
GROUP BY u2.user_id

-- and here's the magic: order in descending order of "distance" between
-- our selected user and all of the others: you may wish to weight
-- self_ranking differently to item scores, in which case just multiply
-- appropriately
ORDER BY SUM(ABS(s2.score - s1.score))
       + ABS(u2.self_ranking - u1.self_ranking) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm afraid that I'm getting an error on the user_id join because I mistakenly listed the database format wrong. In the users table, it's simply id (as edited above).

Comment: @MorganteOrionPell: Then replace `USING (user_id)` with `ON s1.user_id = u1.id` etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ASC on the end, not DESC? I want to find the user with the *least* difference.

Answer (score 1):

In a slight refinement on @eggyal's method, I incorporated the number of items we are able to match against.

```
SELECT   u2.user_id

-- join our user to their scores
FROM     (users u1 JOIN scores s1 USING (user_id))

-- and then join other users and their scores
    JOIN (users u2 JOIN scores s2 USING (user_id))
      ON s1.item_id  = s2.item_id
     AND u1.user_id != u2.user_id

-- filter for our user of interest
WHERE    u1.user_id = ?

-- group other users' scores together
GROUP BY u2.user_id

-- subtract the degree of difference in correlating scores from the number of correlating scores
ORDER BY (SUM(s1.item_id = s2.item_id) - 
  ( SUM(ABS(s2.score - s1.score) + ABS(u2.self - u1.self) ) ) ) DESC
```