# How to use GROUP_CONCAT functionality without GROUP BY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

This is the original SQL statement to retrieve course data:

```
SELECT
    `courses`.`id` AS `id`,
    `courses`.`title` AS `title`,
    `courses`.`description` AS `description`,
    MATCH (coursedata.title) AGAINST ('Salsa') * 5 + MATCH (coursedata.description) AGAINST ('Salsa') * 2 AS `relevance`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(trainers.name SEPARATOR '|||') AS `trainers`
FROM `courses`
INNER JOIN `coursedata` ON `courses`.`id` = `coursedata`.`id`
        INNER JOIN `courses_trainers` ON `courses`.`id` = `courses_trainers`.`course_id`
INNER JOIN `trainers` ON `trainer_id` = `trainers`.`id`
GROUP BY `courses`.`id`
HAVING `relevance` >= '3'
```

Since it uses the [`MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) and cannot be executed, if the `sql_mode` is set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, I had to make it standard SQL conform:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        `courses`.`id` AS `id`,
        `courses`.`title` AS `title`,
        `courses`.`description` AS `description`,
        MATCH (coursedata.title) AGAINST ('Salsa') * 5 + MATCH (coursedata.description) AGAINST ('Salsa') * 2 AS `relevance`
        -- , GROUP_CONCAT(trainers.name SEPARATOR '|||') AS `trainers`
    FROM `courses`
    INNER JOIN `coursedata` ON `courses`.`id` = `coursedata`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `courses_trainers` ON `courses`.`id` = `courses_trainers`.`course_id`
    LEFT JOIN `trainers` ON `trainer_id` = `trainers`.`id`
) AS subselect
WHERE `relevance` >= '3'
```

This one wors fine, but I cannot use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function (in order to concatenate multiple `trainer` fields to one field/string) anymore.

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP_CONCAT(trainers.name SEPARATOR '|||') AS `trainers`
    FROM `courses`
    INNER' at line 7
```

Is there another way to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` functionality?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. You need  group context in order to use GROUP_CONCAT, would would you be concatenating if you weren't grouping by the course.  And why would you just not group by all the fields other than trainers if this no need to operate in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.

Comment: I cannot use the first statement, since `relevance` is an aggregated column. And when I use the second one with `GROUP BY` (`GROUP BY subselect.id, subselect.title, subselect.description`), I also get an error: `Error Code: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause`.

Comment: Use your **1st** query and list **all non-aggregated columns** in the `GROUP BY` clause. This way you will not rely on extensions and wouldn't care about the settings.

Comment: You mean `SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN .. JOIN ... GROUP BY courses.id, courses.id, courses.title, courses.description, coursedata.title, coursedata.description HAVING relevance >= '3'`? It does not work in `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` `sql_mode`: `Error Code: 1463 Non-grouping field 'relevance' is used in HAVING clause`

Comment: @automatix You have to group by relevance as well.

Comment: Solved : 
[Group_Concat() in SQL: Solved][1]
Please Check this post. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20262372/3045124