# MySQL join query on post with categories, only return one result per post

Tags: mysql, sql

This is very basic, I know, but I tend to happen on this issue often.

**Tables**

```
mysql> describe Posts;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Time      | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe PostCategories;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pid      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Category | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT P.id AS pid, P.Time, PC.Category FROM Posts P
LEFT OUTER JOIN PostCategories PC ON PC.pid = P.id
WHERE PC.Category IN('value1','value2') OR PC.Category IS NULL
ORDER BY P.Time DESC
```

**Returns**

```
+-----+------------+----------+
| pid | Time       | Category |
+-----+------------+----------+
|   8 | 1396906256 | NULL     |
|   7 | 1396524835 | value1   |
|   7 | 1396524835 | value2   |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

**Desired outcome**

I would like it to only give me one row for every pid. In other words, no matter how many categories the Post have, I want it to only result in one row in the result dataset.

```
+-----+------------+----------+
| pid | Time       | Category |
+-----+------------+----------+
|   8 | 1396906256 | NULL     |
|   7 | 1396524835 | value1   |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

Category result does not matter, I will not fetch it once it works as I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.id AS pid, MIN(P.Time) as first_post_time, MAX(PC.Category) as Category FROM Posts P
LEFT OUTER JOIN PostCategories PC ON PC.pid = P.id
WHERE PC.Category IN('value1','value2') OR PC.Category IS NULL
GROUP BY P.id
ORDER BY P.Time DESC
```

Just add group by and calculate time and category (use min or max)

Comment: Well, that was obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Group posts by using `Group By` and you can also get all categories if you want by using [group_concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql) procedure in `mysql`.

```
SELECT P.id AS pid, P.Time, GROUP_CONCAT(PC.Category, ' , ') FROM Posts P
LEFT OUTER JOIN PostCategories PC ON PC.pid = P.id
WHERE PC.Category IN('value1','value2') OR PC.Category IS NULL
GROUP BY P.pid
ORDER BY P.Time DESC
```