# How to convert rows into column values in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I need a help to convert sql table rows into columns.

Shown below is the sample data:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       A       12
1       B       23
1       C       43
2       A       32
2       B       54
2       C       76
```

I want to convert this into:

```
Col1    A       B       C
1       12      23      43
2       32      54      76
```

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this. I have never done such queries before.

Thanks in advance ,
Vinay

Comment: click this [TAG: Pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot)

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP\_CONCAT in a CONCAT in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

Comment: Check the post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works with MySQL:

```
select 
    col1,
    sum(case col2 when 'A' then col3 end) as A,
    sum(case col2 when 'B' then col3 end) as B,
    sum(case col2 when 'C' then col3 end) as C
from
    yourTable
group by
    col1
```

Also, read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can Create a Pivot Table in SQL Server

```
Select col1, col2, col3, col4 
from tablname
Pivot 
(
Sum(col) for tablname in ([col2],[col3],[col4])
) 
 as PivotTable
```

Comment: I think you mean SQL server... am I right? Remember: SQL is short for "structured query language", not for a specific RDBMS.

Comment: ya, its for SQL Server only, Use Pivot table, and convert rows into column name

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #t(Col1 int,Col2 varchar(1),Col3 int)
insert into #t values(1,'A', 12),
(1,'B',23),
(1,'C',43),
(2,'A',32),
(2,'B',54),
(2,'C',76)
```

-- `sql server` solution

```
select * from #t
    pivot
    (
    max(col3)
    for col2 in([A],[B],[c])
    )as piv;
```

--`sql server` with `dynamic sql example`

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @query nvarchar(max);

select @cols=stuff((select distinct ','+QUOTENAME(col2) from #t for xml path(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)') ,1,1,'');

select @query='select * from #t
pivot
(
max(col3)
for col2 in('+@cols+')
)as piv;' 

exec(@query)
```

--this might work in `sql-server` `mysql` `oracle` or other *RDBMS*? (as answered by Barranka)

```
select 
    col1,
    sum(case col2 when 'A' then col3 end) as A,
    sum(case col2 when 'B' then col3 end) as B,
    sum(case col2 when 'C' then col3 end) as C
from
    #t
group by
    col1
```