# Sql query issue in php storing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

In simple search form,if we search 1232 we get word stored as in given table we get cat from db using simple query `select 'word' from 'dawat' where counting ='%$term%'` samely 2454 for dog and so on.
Form code:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="get" >
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and tables in db:

```
counting  word

1232      cat
2454      dog
4844      fish
7785      goat
```

Now,it is working correctly,problem is if multiple queries have same value how can we store in mysql.Suppose, all different no. have same value i.e. cat,so we can store normally like:

```
counting  word

1232      cat
2454      cat
4844      cat
7785      cat
```

This is how we can make different coloumns for single.Now,main question is how can i assign all different to fetch cat storing in single coloumn like:

```
   counting             word

1232,2454,4844,7785      cat

5785,4577,9644,6549      dog
```

Comment: You can use the like keyword in sql to search within the specific record. Let me know if you need help with syntax

Comment: I think you can try to use `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: How to do that @PavanJiwnani

Comment: I think @LLL gave you good direction

Comment: I got something about concat like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql but in this column is in group,how can i reverse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something of this sort (***edited***):

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(dawat.counting SEPARATOR ',') AS counting, 
  dawat.word
FROM
  dawat
GROUP BY
  dawat.word;
```

in case concatenated values should be ordered you could use this version:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(dawat.counting ORDER BY dawat.counting ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS counting, 
  dawat.word
FROM
  dawat
GROUP BY
  dawat.word;
```

Comment: But tab,name how to replace as in like full table name searchengine or like counting/word as i described in question?Pls help i 'm new to php.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact you gave table name `dawat` at the beginning of your question.

Comment: Ok,i got a idea.I had tried this also and your anwer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql

Comment: So I'm glad you got the help needed - I hope a complete one