# How to prevent duplicate rows with a 1 to many SQL result without losing data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a blog posts table and a blog post tags table. One post has many tags. I first did this with a call to posts then a loop and call the tags table, but this resulted in 9 queries per page just to get the posts. I have rewritten this to use a join, but it returns duplicate blog posts rows.

```
SELECT p.timestamp
     , p.title
     , p.postcontent
     , p.siteid
     , t.tag 
  FROM user_blogposts p
  LEFT 
  JOIN user_blogposttags t
    ON t.postid = p.id 
 WHERE p.userid = 1 
 LIMIT 8
```

This query returns the data I want, but if there are 5 tags per post, each post will be duplicated 5 times with only the tag field being different. I can't use GROUP BY as this will return 1 row with 1 tag for each post and break the one to many connection.

Is there a way to return an array for the many join so that I only get 1 row for the post and then the tag column is an array or comma delimited string for me to work with rather than having to filter out all of the duplicate data.

Comment: You should use GROUP BY to get unique records...

Comment: this is going to break the many relationship. i will get 1 row with 1 tag even if there are several

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql

Comment: You can use sub query to get the tags. And use `group_concat()` to get the tags as comma separated

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @JasonKennaly this looks like it is for a single table. I could achieve the same comma delimited string by looping the results. It will still result in me having to make 9 queries to the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT user_blogposts.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag) FROM user_blogposttags WHERE user_blogposttags.postid=user_blogposts.id) AS tags
FROM user_blogposts
```

May need minor changes as per your table structure

Comment: thank you, this is really helpful to know

Comment: Right..there is no limit to learning..

Answer (score 1):

You can group and concat the tags like this:

```
SELECT p.timestamp, p.title, p.postcontent, p.siteid, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag SEPERATOR ",") AS tags
FROM user_blogposts p
LEFT JOIN user_blogposttags t
ON t.postid = p.id 
GROUP BY p.timestamp, p.title, p.postcontent, p.siteid;
```

Comment: thanks for the response. There was another answer that used the same method posted first, but i gave an upvote for your answer as the GROUP_CONCAT solution worked perfectly. thank you