# php mysql select data to gridview

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]

when select data from database using php-mysql and display in html table it shows as **(A)**.

but i want to display it as **(b)**

help me...

Comment: What? Please updated your question with expected output and a better explanation

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this. As said by Sagi, do update you question with more details.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to achieve (exclude the repeating Dates and Nums from the rows), but you have to show us PHP code that handles the output so that useful suggestions could be made.

Comment: i'm looking for sample code to start..

Comment: Look for `GROUP_CONCAT()`, there are a lot of questions similar to this. (Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Date)`

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample (and very simple) code would be:

```
// assuming the PDO connection is established and kept in $db
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT Date, Num, Value1, Value2 FROM the_table");
if ($st->execute()) {
    $previousDate = NULL;
    $previousNum = NULL;
    while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        if ($previousDate != $row['Date']) {
            echo $row['Date'];
            $previousDate = $row['Date'];
        }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        if ($previousNum != $row['Num']) {
            echo $row['Num'];
            $previousNum = $row['Num'];
        }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['Value1'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['Value2'] .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```