# Outputting sql data horizontally

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

**Nevermind.. I'm on Oracle 10g, which means none of the easy concat functions of newer Oracle versions or other SQL versions will work.**

I'm looking through one table(payroll) that has duplicates in a column (process_date). The DB is an Oracle DB.

For example table Payroll:

```
Yr  |  Week |  Process_date
15     53       12/19/2015
15     52       12/19/2015
15     51       12/7/2015
```

I would want the output to return the weeks that had the same processing date with the week numbers on the same line like this

```
Yr  |  Week 1|  Week 2 | Process_date
15     53       52        12/19/2015
```

I've tried various sub-selects and joins, but can't get it right.

EDIT: Added detail
EDIT2: Ended topic

Comment: Which database are you using?  And it sounds like you want to `pivot` your results.  If you know the number of potential columns, there are a couple ways to do this depending on the rdbms.  If you don't know the number of columns, then you'll need to use `dynamic sql`.

Comment: This is a crosstab or pivot query. How to make this happen will depend strongly on which RDBMS you are using. You should update your question to tag the RDBMS (mysql vs sql-server vs postgresql vs...)

Comment: @sgeddes, that is what I was trying to avoid. I can just export the results to excel and pivot it there.. much easier for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Yr, GROUP_CONCAT(Week SEPARATOR ',') Weeks, Process_date
FROM payroll 
GROUP BY Yr, Process_date;
```

This will give you the following output:

```
Yr | Weeks | Process_date
15   53,52   12/19/2015
```

If you must get them in separate columns, you may need a subquery as follow. This query will not work properly if you only have one week, not two.

```
SELECT Yr, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Weeks, ',', 1), ',', -1) Week1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Weeks, ',', 2), ',', -1) Week2, Process_date
FROM
    (SELECT Yr, GROUP_CONCAT(Week SEPARATOR ',') Weeks, Process_date
    FROM payroll 
    GROUP BY Yr, Process_date) merged_payroll;
```

Output:

```
Yr | Weeks | Process_date
15   53,52   12/19/2015
15   51,51   12/7/2015  (DUPLICATED 51)
```

Reference: (1) [How to use GROUP_CONCAT in a CONCAT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql) (2) [Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two)

Comment: This `SELECT Yr, GROUP_CONCAT(Week SEPARATOR ',') Weeks, Process_date` gives me this error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: Nevermind.. I'm on Oravle 10g, which means non of the easy concat functions of newer Oracle versions or other SQL versions will work. Thanks for the help though.