# Make multiple row result to one row SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create

```
select c.FullName, b.*, e.Description as Posisilama, f.Description as Posisibaru, g.Description,
       GROUP_CONCAT('b.nilai' SEPARATOR ',') AS nilai
from penilaian_header a
    left join penilaian_detail b on a.KodePenilaian = b.KodePenilaianH
    left join employee c on a.Nip = c.Nip
    left join HistoryPosition d on a.KodePenilaian = d.KodePenilaian    
    left join Position e on d.OldPosition = e.PositionCode
    left join Position f on d.NewPosition = f.PositionCode
    left join Outlet g on c.OutletCode = g.OutletCode
```

Can you check my query, because I got this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'SEPARATOR'

What I need to do is to make multiple row result in to one row SQL. Because my result is like this

[image]

I found a solution. I use pivot.

```
select * from 
            (
             select row, c.Nilai,b.Fullname,a.KodePenilaian,d.Description from penilaian_header a 
            left join employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip 
            left join outlet d on a.Outlet = d.OutletCode
            left join (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KodePenilaianH ORDER BY idPenilaiand DESC) AS Row, Nilai,KodePenilaianH from penilaian_Detail
            ) c on a.KodePenilaian = c.KodePenilaianH where a.Outlet like '%%' and Periode like '%%'
            ) nilai 
            pivot
            (
            sum(nilai)
            for row in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
            ) piv;
```

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause. (And remove single quotes around column names.)

Comment: There is no `Group_concat` in MS SQL Server.

Comment: RDBMS is tagged wrongly

Comment: Check STUFF function instead of Group_concat, that's for TSQL

Comment: How do you want to group this in one row? what will you do to the column2,3,4? They have different values

Comment: @Kim ok  . I will remove column 2 & 3

Comment: @AndyKorneyev . So are there any method(s) ?

Comment: Change the quotes around _b.nilai_ to back tics (or just remove the quotes)

Comment: So what RDBMS are you using? Your tags say SQL Server, your SQL statement tells something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

miss a group by clause,check this :
[How to use GROUP_CONCAT in a CONCAT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

i will write like this :

```
select c.FullName, b.*, e.Description as Posisilama
, f.Description as Posisibaru, g.Description,
       GROUP_CONCAT('b.nilai' SEPARATOR ',') AS nilai
from penilaian_header a
    left join penilaian_detail b on a.KodePenilaian = b.KodePenilaianH
    left join employee c on a.Nip = c.Nip
    left join HistoryPosition d on a.KodePenilaian = d.KodePenilaian    
    left join Position e on d.OldPosition = e.PositionCode
    left join Position f on d.NewPosition = f.PositionCode
    left join Outlet g on c.OutletCode = g.OutletCode  
group by  c.FullName, b.*, e.Description 
, f.Description , g.Description
```