# Query is not executing properly when I use GROUP_CONCAT with in keyward

Tags: mysql

I am try to run sub query with NOT IN keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM user_group_master WHERE user_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT("'",userid,"'") FROM location_sharing_setting WHERE owner_id = '123456' AND sharing_status = 0)
```

Query is running properly when we didn't use sub query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM user_group_master WHERE user_id NOT IN ('56556','540003')
```

Please Help me with best solution ...

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `GROUP_CONCAT` to use `IN()` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) 
FROM user_group_master
 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id
                   FROM location_sharing_setting
                   WHERE owner_id = '123456' AND sharing_status = 0)
```

You can either specify a list inside the `IN()` statement, like `'123','234',..`
.

Or you can specify a query, that output the same column like

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Col IN(SELECT Same_Col FROM OtherTable)
```