# How can I merge values of existing rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have to get all results and push to HTML table, but existing rows have to be combine to 1 row.

This is my table

```
id   domain       php_version
-----------------------------
1    localhost    5.5.30
2    live         7.05
3    localhost    5.5.30
4    localhost    5.5.30
```

and the code which output the html table is:

```
// Prepare query
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM domains ORDER BY domain ASC LIMIT 10");
// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();
// Bind Parameters
$stmt->bind_result($id, $domain, $php_version);

<?php while ($stmt->fetch()) : ?>
<tr class="row-id-<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <td class="id"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td class="domain"><?php echo $domain; ?></td>
    <td class="php_version"><?php echo $php_version; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

And I just want to be like this:

[image]

I just want to combine values of dublicated domains in one row/column

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you order by `domain`, then your real output differs from what you show us.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think that I managed to do it with group_concat:

```
SELECT domain,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT php_version SEPARATOR '\n' ) php_versions,
       ...
FROM domains GROUP BY domain
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the results out of mysql and into a regular PHP array (called $array in my code), and then this snippet will do what you want:

```
function sort_by_php_version($a, $b)
{
    if ($a["php_version"] == $b["php_version"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["php_version"] < $b["php_version"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

$array = [
["id"=>1, "domain"=>"localhost", "php_version"=>"5.5.30"], 
["id"=>2, "domain"=>"live", "php_version"=>"7.05"], 
["id"=>3, "domain"=>"localhost", "php_version"=>"5.5.30"], 
["id"=>4, "domain"=>"localhost", "php_version"=>"5.5.30"], 
];

usort($array, "sort_by_php_version");

$in_domain = null;
$output_array = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
    $thisRow = $array[$i];
    $domain = $thisRow["domain"];
    if ($domain == $in_domain) {
        $output_array[count($output_array) - 1]["php_versions"][] = $thisRow["php_version"];
    } else {
        $thisRow["php_versions"] = array($thisRow["php_version"]);
        unset($thisRow["php_version"]);
        $output_array[] = $thisRow;

        $in_domain  = $domain;
    }
}

var_dump($output_array);
```

Comment: OK, but when I have more columns in future?

Comment: You should be constructing your `$array' dynamically from database as opposed it being hardcoded with values here. In which case, when you add more columns, just change the iteration loop to include those columns and do whatever you want with them. It cannot be predict predicted what kind of column changes you will make, so the scope of that is to broad to answer here.