# Is there a way to get all values associated with foreign key joined in a tuple?

Tags: mysql, join

I use a relation looking like :

[image: Relations]
In Mysql.

NB:

> clientss 1..N evenements_clients
>
> evenements_types 1..N evenements_clients

Or, if I got it wrong again,

> 1 client can have many evenements_clients
>
> 1 evenements_types can have many evenements_clients

And I'm looking for a way to join evenements_types such as I get a tuple like

**Considering EtCode equals EvType**

```
ClNum, ClNom, EtCode1, EtCode2, EtCode3, EtCode4 ... (as many as there are)
```

and not vertically

```
ClNum, ClNom, EtCode1
ClNum, ClNom, EtCode2
ClNum, ClNom, EtCode3
ClNum, ClNom, EtCode4
```

I used Phpstorm to generate the image.

[Partial Answer to the question in another question, as it is now within one cell.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

Comment: You should investigate the query clauses `GROUP_CONCAT(EtCode) ... GROUP BY`

Comment: Ah, found something thanks to you.

Comment: Bear in mind you're seriously bending the rules of relational DB design and usage here.  Great if it works for you in the odd one-off situation but if you find yourself doing it a lot, you probably need to rethink what you're doing, especially if the tuple itself has variable columns as opposed to a single separated value.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of realised that. I'm going to stay with group concat I suppose.