# MySQL joining two tables with specific output

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried searching around but could not find the answer, because maybe of my keyword, but I am hoping someone could help.
I have two tables like this :

```
+----+---------+
| ID | Parents |
+----+---------+
| 1  |  David  |
| 2  |  Peter  |
+----+---------+
```

The other table is:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID | Parents_id | Child_name |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  |      1     |    Mike    |
| 2  |      1     |    John    |
| 3  |      2     |    Chris   |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Now on my browser, i wanted to have list something like this,

```
+---------+----------+
| Parents | Children |
+---------+----------+
| David   |  - Mike  |
|         |  - John  |
+---------+----------+
| Peter   |  Chris   |
+---------+----------+
```

Can use php or jquery to get it done.

Comment: how is this related to jquery?

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help fix issues with code you've written, not provide free code. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

Comment: The "keywords" you are looking for are "mysql tutorial join tables". You will find plenty of example code. Try out the code, update your question with the **code** you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get comma separated values from the query and format it in the browser, e.g.:

```
SELECT t1.parents, 
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(child_name) FROM table2 WHERE parents_id = t1.ID GROUP BY parents_id) AS Children
FROM table1 t1;
```

Comment: You can format non csv results more easily.