# How to concatenate names in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have query:

```
SELECT YEAR(t1.changedtime) as year, MONTHNAME(t1.changedtime) as months, t6.pname FROM `working_scene` t1 
LEFT JOIN( SELECT longname, username, user_type, email, uid, staff_id, access, fkdeptid, fkhouseid, fkhouseroleid FROM `users` )t2 ON t2.uid = t1.owner 
LEFT JOIN( SELECT longname as squad_leader, uid FROM `users` )t3 ON t3.uid = t1.fkslid 
LEFT JOIN( SELECT weid, fkwpid FROM `working_episode` )t4 ON t4.weid = t1.fkweid 
LEFT JOIN( SELECT wpid, fkpid, fkrftid FROM `working_project` )t5 ON t5.wpid = t4.fkwpid 
LEFT JOIN( SELECT pid, pname FROM `master_project` )t6 ON t6.pid = t5.fkpid WHERE t2.staff_id = '1000368' GROUP BY t6.pname, months ORDER BY changedtime ASC
```

Which will give me the result:

[image]

How can I delete month duplication and print project names coma separated within one month?

For example:

```
| year |  months  |  pname   |
+------+----------+----------+
| 2016 | November | Hanazuki |
| 2016 | November | Niko     |
```

To be:

```
| year |  months  |     pname      |
+------+----------+----------------+
| 2016 | November | Hanazuki, Niko |
```

**EDIT**

I tried `group_concat` but it didnt work the way I wanted. Here is what

```
SELECT YEAR(t1.changedtime) as year, 
       MONTHNAME(t1.changedtime) as months,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t6.pname)
FROM `working_scene` t1 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT longname, username, user_type, email, uid, staff_id, access, fkdeptid, fkhouseid, fkhouseroleid FROM `users` )t2 ON t2.uid = t1.owner 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT longname as squad_leader, uid FROM `users` )t3 ON t3.uid = t1.fkslid 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT weid, fkwpid FROM `working_episode` )t4 ON t4.weid = t1.fkweid 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT wpid, fkpid, fkrftid FROM `working_project` )t5 ON t5.wpid = t4.fkwpid 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT pid, pname FROM `master_project` )t6 ON t6.pid = t5.fkpid 
WHERE t2.staff_id = '1000368' 
GROUP BY YEAR(t1.changedtime), MONTHNAME(t1.changedtime)
ORDER BY changedtime ASC
```

[image]

Comment: You are looking for group_concat

Comment: How to use `group_concat`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has built-in aggregate function for that called [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT YEAR(t1.changedtime) as year, 
       MONTHNAME(t1.changedtime) as months,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t6.pname)
FROM `working_scene` t1 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT longname, username, user_type, email, uid, staff_id, access, fkdeptid, fkhouseid, fkhouseroleid FROM `users` )t2 ON t2.uid = t1.owner 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT longname as squad_leader, uid FROM `users` )t3 ON t3.uid = t1.fkslid 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT weid, fkwpid FROM `working_episode` )t4 ON t4.weid = t1.fkweid 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT wpid, fkpid, fkrftid FROM `working_project` )t5 ON t5.wpid = t4.fkwpid 
      LEFT JOIN( SELECT pid, pname FROM `master_project` )t6 ON t6.pid = t5.fkpid 
WHERE t2.staff_id = '1000368' 
GROUP BY YEAR(t1.changedtime), MONTHNAME(t1.changedtime)
ORDER BY changedtime ASC
```

Comment: I tried it but it stores all the names inside one row. Please see edit

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy add `DISTINCT` keyword inside the function, `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
 t6.pname)`