# Manipulating duplicate values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, with an `ID`, `FirstName` & `Lastname`.

I'm selecting that using the following query:

```
SELECT USER_ID as [ID], First_P + ' ' + Last_P as FullName FROM Persons
```

It's working fine. I'm basically having a list of ID's and full names.

Full names could be the same. How is it possible for me to find them and add the ID on the Full name cell as well? only when the names are the same.

Example:

```
1      John Wick (1) 
50     John Wick (50)
```

I haven't found any similar questions to be honest, at least not for MSSQL. So If there are any, feel free to link me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP\_CONCAT in a CONCAT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

Comment: @PeterBode That's MySQL and GROUP_CONCAT in SQL-Server I believe. I'll give it a read though!

Comment: Do you want the ID only when there are multiple people with the same name, or on every row?

Comment: @Larnu The one between brackets? I want it to show only when there are multiple people with the same name yes.

Comment: It's worth showing expected results for both side of the coin then, and more than one example; as that makes it clear in your question your actual goal. Looks like you need a `CASE` expression and a `COUNT` with the `OVER` clause. I'm pretty sure there are lots of examples here on how to achieve this. Have a look at those functions and have a go; if you get stuck edit your attempts in and comment back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please take a look my answer. I used nested query to identify number of duplicated names

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  IIF(NUMBEROFDUPS =1, NAME, CONCAT(NAME, ' (', ID, ')')) AS NAME
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ID,
    CONCAT(First_P, ' ', Last_P) AS NAME,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY First_P,Last_P) AS NUMBEROFDUPS 
  FROM 
    Table1
) tmp;
```

Comment: I keep getting incorrect syntax with the last row (the `);`) and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outer apply to group the items via `First_P + ' ' + Last_P`

and then add case for multiple items.

The select stuff should look like:

```
   SELECT USER_ID as [ID], p1.First_P + ' ' + p1.Last_P + case when cnt.FullName is not null 
        then '(' + p2.[sum] + ')' else '' end as FullName FROM Persons p1
        outer apply (select First_P + ' ' + Last_P as FullName,count(1) as [sum]
                     from Persons p2
                     where p2.First_P + ' ' + p2.Last_P = p1.First_P + ' ' + p1.Last_P
                     group by First_P + ' ' + Last_P
                     having count(1) > 1) cnt
```