# Duplication of results after selecting data from two tables with the same values

Tags: php, sql, join, select, duplicates

Good day! I'm having a problem in duplication of results when I'm selecting data from two tables with the same values. I have one data in my first table `homepost` with an ID of `2` and I have three data in table `multiple` with an ID of `2`.

So. In my source code. I'm selecting all the data with the same values `ID`. But it duplicates my one data from `homepost` because I have three data from `multiple` with the same values `[ID]`. Any help? Thank you!

For example in the table below:

```
Table [homepost]                    Table [multiple]

homeID   homeDesc               multipleID     multipleImage
2          John                     2              Image1
3        Samantha                   2              Image2
                                    2              Image3
                                    3              Image4
                                    3              Image5
```

Results of my code:

```
John
Image1
John
Image2
John
Image3
Samantha
Image4
Samantha
Image5
```

What I want is:

```
John
Image1
Image2
Image3

Samantha
Image4
Image5
```

Here's my Source Code:

```
<?php
    include ("dbconnect.php");

    $content_sql="SELECT post.postID, post.postTitle, post.postDesc, post.postImage 
                    FROM post 
                        JOIN category ON (post.categoryID=category.categoryID) 
                    WHERE post.categoryID=".$_GET['categoryID'];

    if($content_query=mysqli_query($con, $content_sql)) {
        $content_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($content_query);
    }

do {
    echo $content_rs['postTitle'];
    echo $content_rs['postDesc'];
} while ($content_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($content_query))

?>
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: I'm just starting to understand how PHP works for now because I am just a beginner. I think security comes later.

Comment: You can use group_concat for this whcih will return all multipleImage name in comma separated form. Have a look of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check the name each time round the loop and only output it if its a new one

```
<?php
include ("dbconnect.php");

$sql="SELECT post.postID, post.postTitle, post.postDesc, post.postImage 
      FROM post 
          JOIN category ON (post.categoryID=category.categoryID) 
      WHERE post.categoryID=?";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['categoryID']);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

$last_name = '';        
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    if ( $last_name != $row['postTitle'] ) {
        echo $row['postTitle'];
        $last_name = $row['postTitle'];
    }

    echo $row['postDesc'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried this one. This works with the `postTitle`. But the `postDesc` doesn't work because it is echoed by `content_rs` and it says `Unidentified Variable`. Any solution? I know it will get the error because there's no variable `$content_rs` to start with.

Comment: Check the code again. I also made it bind the $GET parameter

Comment: Nevermind. I just changed `$content_rs` into `$row`. Its working now. Thanks alot!