# Convert MySQL table from vertical to horizontal based on id column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

```
id | main_id       | image
1  | 10            | 52343.jpg   
2  | 10            | 52344.jpg  
3  | 10            | 52345.jpg 
4  | 11            | 52346.jpg   
5  | 11            | 52347.jpg  
6  | 11            | 52348.jpg 
7  | 11            | 52349.jpg   
8  | 12            | 52350.jpg  
9  | 12            | 52351.jpg
```

i want output like this :

```
id | main_id  | image1    
1  | 10       | 52343.jpg, 52344.jpg, 52345.jpg 
2  | 11       | 52346.jpg, 52347.jpg, 52348.jpg, 52349.jpg 
3  | 12       | 52350.jpg, 52351.jpg
```

Just all images with same main_id to be in one row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP\_CONCAT in a CONCAT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group_concat()`

```
select main_id,group_concat(image)
from tablename
group by main_id
```

Comment: It works fine, but I noticed that that there are max number of characters that the 'image' cell can accommodate. i.e. if there are 100 jpg file name to be accommodated, it can only store limited number with fixed characters and the rest do not show. Any idea?

Comment: How to put results in multi columns i.e. image1, image2, image3 ..... not in image column only?