# sql query to select record having same id but different values in two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I tried for hours and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request

I have a table like this

```
Name        Phone

John        62778282
Alok        67828888
Rahul       68999999
Yash        97788899
John        99989999
Rahul       99992222
```

The output should be something like:

```
Name        Phone

John        62778282 , 99989999
Alok        67828888
Rahul       68999999 , 99992222
Yash        97788899
```

Please Anybody help me to get this result

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql) question. It has a bit more complicated case than yours, but it's using what you need. You need to group concat the phone numbers and group by name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP\_CONCAT in a CONCAT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

Comment: You mention PHP, so consider handling display issues there instead

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
    `Name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Phone`) AS `Phone`
FROM `Table`
GROUP BY `Name`;
```

Result [SQL query](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=813c00d367db64e01176b999d90819b7&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

```
+=======+===================+
| Name  | Phone             |
+=======+===================+
| Alok  | 67828888          |
| John  | 62778282,99989999 |
| Rahul | 62778282,99992222 |
| Yash  | 97788899          |
+-------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

`Group By` And `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Phone) AS Phone  FROM phonetable GROUP BY Name
```